# Qt Bind slot and signal failed QMainWindow QWebview

Tags: c++, qt

## .h file:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include "tool/shape.h"
#include "tool/sensor.h"
#include "tool/sensor_set.h"
#include "tool/track_unit.h"
#include "tool/track.h"
#include "tool/track_set.h"
#include "tool/opera.h"

class QWebView;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
protected Q_SLOTS:
    void test();
    //void startOpera();

public:
Q_SIGNALS:
    void updateObject(const QString& data);

private:
    //Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWebView* m_webView;
tools::Opera2D* opera;
tools::Opera2D::Iterator *iter;
tools::Opera2D::OperaState* opera_state;

QTimer* m_timerOpera;

};
```

## .cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
//ui(new Ui::MainWindow)*/
{
    m_webView = new QWebView(this);
    QUrl url = QUrl("file:///F:/WORKSTATON/SVN/txm/txm/google/index.html");
    m_webView->load(url);
    setCentralWidget(m_webView);
    move(QPoint(200, 200));
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(updateObject(const QString&)),
           m_webView->page()->mainFrame(), SLOT(evaluateJavaScript(const QString&)));
}
```

## mingw g++ show:

### error:

```
F:\WORKSTATON\SVN\tools_temp\mainwindow.cpp:162: error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(MainWindow* const, const char*, QWebFrame*, const char*)'
                m_webView->page()->mainFrame(), SLOT(evaluateJavaScript(const QString&)));
```

### error:

```
D:\Program\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtCore\qobject.h:215: error: no type named 'Object' in 'struct QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<const char*>'
```

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? If you are on Qt 5, you can use the new connect style with function pointers that often produces better error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the following checkboxes ticked:

- Q_OBJECT macro not missing
- signals well marked
- slots well marked
- argument numbers are matching
- argument types are matching
- You do not have a typo
- You are inheriting QObject
- You are using pointers for the sender and receiver
- You run qmake for the latest state
- etc

The reason is that you forgot to include the header file for the returned heap object, namely:

```
#include <QWebFrame>
```

For future reference: given that you use Qt 5.3.1, you could try using this form should you have Qt 5 available on other supported platforms, too, or conditionally at least:

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::updateObject,
        m_webView->page()->mainFrame(), &QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript);
```

Having said that, you have other minor issues with your code, but they are only tangentially related:

- signals in your scenario do not make much sense as being marked `public` in the header.
- It is unusual for the receiver to be `this` object; in other words, you may reconsider your design why not just calling the slot directly where you would emit or connect from this receiver in other place of your codebase.

Comment: As far as my research tells me, you don't need C++11 for the new connect style as long as you are not using lambda slots.

Comment: @SimonWarta: you are correct, of course, updated, appreciated, thanks.